# Horizontally centre fluid div of multiple rows

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout, liquid-layout

I want to achieve the expected layout below (first image) but stuck with actual layout (second one)

[image]

Here is how I started

```
.parent .child{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px 2px 2px 2px;
    background: #000;
}
```

How can i take it further to expected layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep css :change float left to display:inline-block

```
.parent{ text-align: center;}
.parent .child{
 display:inline-block;
 width: 25%;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 5px 2px 2px 2px;
 background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/C9zxt/1/)**

css:

```
.parent{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;

}
.parent .child{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px 2px 2px 2px;
    background: #000;
}
```